# Django - PostgreSQL 9 - what is the maximum value of a PositiveIntegerField?

Tags: django, postgresql

The Django docs assure me that `PositiveIntegerField()` will always be able to store values up to 2,147,483,647, but I'd like to know whether this value is actually higher if I'm using PostgreSQL 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the PostgreSQL manual, the [datatypes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype.html), for the integer type:

```
integer 4 bytes typical choice for integer  -2147483648 to +2147483647
```